# 'contact list' exercise not running correctly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Codecademy code**

I have successfully completed a JavaScript exercise in Codecademy entitled 'contact list' with the code:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};

var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
};

list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

This outputs:

> bill
>
> steve
>
> { firstName: 'Steve',
>
> lastName: 'Jobs',
>
> number: '(408) 555-5555',
>
> address: [ '1 Infinite Loop', 'Cupertino', 'CA', '95014' ] }
>
> {"firstName":"Steve",
>
> "lastName":"Jobs",
>
> "number":"(408) 555-5555",
>
> "address":["1 >Infinite Loop","Cupertino","CA","95014"]}

---

I then changed the list and search functions slightly so that it outputs in chrome correctly:

```
var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    document.write(prop + "<br>");
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      document.write(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
};
```

This returned the output:

> bill
>
> steve
>
> [object Object]

**Question**:

Where does this `[object Object]` output come from?

How can I return the correct output from search function?

**Note**:

The list function is working fine, but there is a problem with the search function. The `friends[prop].firstName` in the for loop is not returning anything.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `[object Object]` is the default string representation of a Javascript object.  You will get that when you try to `write` out any object.  In your example, `console.log` does a bit of magic that converts for you automatically:

```js
document.write({});
document.write({ a: 'b' });
```

What you can do to output a more helpful version of a JS Object is using JSON.  Thankfully, JS provides a nice little function for converting objects into strings:

```js
document.write(JSON.stringify({}));
document.write(JSON.stringify({ a: 'b' }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the JSON.stringify({}); function, very useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`document.write(friends[prop])` shows oupput as `[object Object]`, access property by property name.

```
var search = function (name) {
        for (var prop in friends) {
            if (friends[prop].firstName === name) {
                //document.write(friends[prop]);
                var oProp = friends[prop]
                document.write(oProp.address + "<br/>" + oProp.firstName);
                //return friends[prop] - as an object
                //return oProp.address - as a single property
                //return JSON.stringify(oProp) - as a JSON string
                return friends[prop];
            }
        }
   };
```